# Error when trying to add a variant in Shopify

Tags: shopify, variant

I am trying to add a variant to the existing Product id. 
Below is the JSON request which i had done. However i am getting an error

```
{"errors":{"variant":"expected Array to be a Hash"}}
```

JSON Request.

```
{"variant": [{"product_id": 10065509898,"title": "XS\/ BROWN","price": 49.05,"sku": "BA1015_BROWN_XS","position": 1,"grams": 0,"inventory_policy": "deny","compare_at_price": null,"fulfillment_service": "manual","inventory_management": "shopify","option1": "BROWN","option2": "XS","option3": null,"taxable": true,"barcode": "800123054849","inventory_quantity": 0,"old_inventory_quantity": 0,"inventory_quantity_adjustment": 1,"weight": 1,"weight_unit": "lb","requires_shipping": true},{"product_id": 10065509898,"title": "S\/ BROWN","price": 49.05,"sku": "BA1015_BROWN_S","position": 2,"grams": 0,"inventory_policy": "deny","compare_at_price": null,"fulfillment_service": "manual","inventory_management": "shopify","option1": "BROWN","option2": "S","option3": null,"taxable": true,"barcode": "800123054856","inventory_quantity": 0,"old_inventory_quantity": 0,"inventory_quantity_adjustment": 1,"weight": 1,"weight_unit": "lb","requires_shipping": true},{"product_id": 10065509898,"title": "M\/ BROWN","price": 49.05,"sku": "BA1015_BROWN_M","position": 3,"grams": 0,"inventory_policy": "deny","compare_at_price": null,"fulfillment_service": "manual","inventory_management": "shopify","option1": "BROWN","option2": "M","option3": null,"taxable": true,"barcode": "800123054863","inventory_quantity": 0,"old_inventory_quantity": 0,"inventory_quantity_adjustment": 1,"weight": 1,"weight_unit": "lb","requires_shipping": true},{"product_id": 10065509898,"title": "L\/ BROWN","price": 49.05,"sku": "BA1015_BROWN_L","position": 4,"grams": 0,"inventory_policy": "deny","compare_at_price": null,"fulfillment_service": "manual","inventory_management": "shopify","option1": "BROWN","option2": "L","option3": null,"taxable": true,"barcode": "800123054870","inventory_quantity": 0,"old_inventory_quantity": 0,"inventory_quantity_adjustment": 1,"weight": 1,"weight_unit": "lb","requires_shipping": true},{"product_id": 10065509898,"title": "XL\/ BROWN","price": 49.05,"sku": "BA1015_BROWN_XL","position": 5,"grams": 0,"inventory_policy": "deny","compare_at_price": null,"fulfillment_service": "manual","inventory_management": "shopify","option1": "BROWN","option2": "XL","option3": null,"taxable": true,"barcode": "800123054887","inventory_quantity": 0,"old_inventory_quantity": 0,"inventory_quantity_adjustment": 1,"weight": 1,"weight_unit": "lb","requires_shipping": true},{"product_id": 10065509898,"title": "XXL\/ BROWN","price": 49.05,"sku": "BA1015_BROWN_XXL","position": 6,"grams": 0,"inventory_policy": "deny","compare_at_price": null,"fulfillment_service": "manual","inventory_management": "shopify","option1": "BROWN","option2": "XXL","option3": null,"taxable": true,"barcode": "800123054894","inventory_quantity": 0,"old_inventory_quantity": 0,"inventory_quantity_adjustment": 1,"weight": 1,"weight_unit": "lb","requires_shipping": true}]}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which URL are you doing a RESTful call on? Is it PUT or POST? Are there any existing variants in the product already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are sending an array of variants. You have to [add each variant](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product_variant#create) separately:

`POST /admin/products/{product_id}/variants.json`

```
{
    "variant": {
        "option1": "BROWN",
        "price": "49.05",
        "sku": "BA1015_BROWN_XS"
     }
}
```

You can pass an array of variants only when you are [creating a new product](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product#create).

Comment: You can also add multiple variants using "PUT" on the product.

Comment: @HymnZ be careful because it will replace existing variants.

Comment: Nope.. You can keep existing variants with the new variants if you provide variant ids in the array.. A nifty hidden feature..